# Google Mailer app inside Django using OAuth 2.0

Tags: python, unit-testing, django, oauth

I have built this [Django Package](https://django-google-mailer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) which is an alternative for sending mail to users using Gmail API. Everything is working fine. But the **verify(self, request)** method inside `gmailer/gmail.py` is not feeling great with the way I coded.

I need to optimize this code and understand if there is a better style of coding that I can adapt here regarding error handling and writing testcases for this code. Here is the [source](https://github.com/nikhiljohn10/django-google-mailer/) to the Django package.

```
from base64 import urlsafe_b64encode
from django.conf import settings
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow

_GMAIL_CONSTS = {
    'GMAIL_SECRET': 'google_client_secret.json',
    'GMAIL_SCOPES': [
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.metadata",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send",
    ],
    'GMAIL_REDIRECT': 'http://localhost:8000/gmailer/verify',
    'GMAIL_USER': 'Django Mail Admin'
}


class Gmail:
    def __init__(self, client_secrets_file, scopes, redirect_uri, user):
        self.activated = False
        self.user = user
        self.outbox = []
        self.flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
            client_secrets_file=client_secrets_file,
            scopes=scopes,
            redirect_uri=redirect_uri)

    def authorize(self):
        return self.flow.authorization_url()

    def verify(self, request):
        code = request.GET.get('code', '')
        state = request.GET.get('state', '')
        if code and 'oauth_state' in request.session and state == request.session['oauth_state']:
            try:
                self.flow.fetch_token(code=code)
                self.credentials = self.flow.credentials
                self.service = build(
                    'gmail', 'v1', credentials=self.credentials)
                self.email = (self.service.users().getProfile(
                    userId="me").execute())['emailAddress']
                self.activated = True
                return {
                    'user': self.user,
                    'email': self.email,
                    'credentials': {
                        'token': self.credentials.token,
                        'refresh_token': self.credentials.refresh_token,
                        'token_uri': self.credentials.token_uri,
                        'client_id': self.credentials.client_id,
                        'client_secret': self.credentials.client_secret,
                        'scopes': self.credentials.scopes,
                    },
                }
            except Exception as err:
                self.revoke()
                return {'message': 'Unable to authorize request', 'error': str(err)}
        else:
            raise self.StateError()

    def revoke(self):
        if hasattr(self, 'service'):
            self.service.close()
        self.activated = False
        self.credentials = None
        self.service = None
        self.email = ''
        self.outbox = []

    def _create_message(self, subject, message_text, from_email, recipient_list, html):
        message = MIMEMultipart()
        message['to'] = ', '.join(recipient_list)
        message['from'] = from_email
        message['subject'] = subject
        if html:
            message.attach(MIMEText(message_text, 'html'))
        else:
            message.attach(MIMEText(message_text, 'plain'))
        raw = urlsafe_b64encode(message.as_bytes()).decode()
        return {'raw': raw}

    def send_mail(self, subject, message, recipient_list, html=False):
        if self.activated:
            try:
                body = self._create_message(
                    subject,
                    message,
                    self.user + " <" + self.email + ">",
                    recipient_list,
                    html)
                sent_message = (self.service.users().messages().send(
                    userId="me",
                    body=body).execute())
                print('Message sent with id: %s' % sent_message['id'])
                return sent_message
            except HttpError as error:
                pass
        else:
            raise self.UnauthorizedAPIError()

    def test_mail(self, subject=None, message=None, recipient_list=None):
        if self.activated:
            try:
                sub = subject or "Django Google Mailer"
                msg = message or "Hi,\n\nWelcome to Django Site"
                to = recipient_list or [self.email]
                sent_message = self.send_mail(sub, msg, to)
                self.outbox.append(sent_message)
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
        else:
            raise self.UnauthorizedAPIError()

    @staticmethod
    def add_settings():
        for attr in ['GMAIL_SECRET', 'GMAIL_SCOPES', 'GMAIL_REDIRECT', 'GMAIL_USER']:
            if not hasattr(settings, attr):
                setattr(settings, attr, _GMAIL_CONSTS[attr])
        installed_apps = getattr(settings, 'INSTALLED_APPS', [])
        installed_apps += ['gmailer', ]
        setattr(settings, 'INSTALLED_APPS', installed_apps)
        return True

    class SettingError(Exception):
        def __init__(self, setting_name, error=None):
            self.message = setting_name + ' is missing/misconfigured inside Django Settings'
            self.error = error
            super().__init__(self.message)

    class StateError(Exception):
        def __init__(self, message=None, error=None):
            self.message = message or "The state/code is not valid. Check the verification url."
            self.error = error
            super().__init__(self.message)

    class UnauthorizedAPIError(Exception):
        def __init__(self, message=None, error=None):
            self.message = message or "Gmail API Service is not authorized. Contact site administrator."
            self.error = error
            super().__init__(self.message)


if Gmail.add_settings():
    mailer = Gmail(
        client_secrets_file=settings.GMAIL_SECRET,
        scopes=settings.GMAIL_SCOPES,
        redirect_uri=settings.GMAIL_REDIRECT,
        user=settings.GMAIL_USER)
```